# Two mysql queries and 2 $results. Can I get the same 2 $results using only one mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Have html input (user enters in html form) like this

```
row_id | debit  | credit |
---------------------------
1      |2610    | 2380
2      |2620    | 2310
3      |5310    | 2621
```

Have mysql table like this

```
TrackPayments | AccountNumber
---------------------------
1             |2610    
1             |2310   
0             |2380   
1             |2620    
1             |2621    
1             |5310
```

Want to get value of column `TrackPayments` for each `debit` and `credit`

At first create arrays `$debit` and `$credit` like that:

```
 foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
 $debit[] = $_POST['debit'][$i];
 }

 foreach ($_POST['row_id'] as $i => $row_id) {
 $credit[] = $_POST['credit'][$i];
 }
```

Then execute 2 queries

```
 $stmt1 = $db->prepare('SELECT TrackPayments FROM users WHERE AccountNumber= ?');
 $stmt1->execute( $debit );
 $result1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $stmt2 = $db->prepare('SELECT TrackPayments FROM users WHERE AccountNumber= ?');
 $stm2->execute( $credit );
 $result2 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And get

`$result1` = `array("1", "1", "1");`

and

`$result2` = `array("0", "1", "1");`

Code is rather long and I do 2 mysql queries. Is it possible to get same result using one mysql query (to use less resources of system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```sql
SELECT debit, u.TrackPayments track_debit,
       credit, u2.TrackPayments track_credit
  FROM
(
  SELECT 2610 debit, 2380 credit UNION ALL
  SELECT 2620, 2310 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5310, 2621 
) q JOIN users u
    ON q.debit = u.AccountNumber JOIN users u2
    ON q.credit = u2.AccountNumber
```

Sample output:

```
| DEBIT | TRACK_DEBIT | CREDIT | TRACK_CREDIT |
|-------|-------------|--------|--------------|
|  2620 |           1 |   2310 |            1 |
|  2610 |           1 |   2380 |            0 |
|  5310 |           1 |   2621 |            1 |
```

or

```sql
SELECT AccountNumber, TrackPayments, 'debit' type
  FROM users
 WHERE AccountNumber IN(2610, 2620, 5310)
 UNION ALL
SELECT AccountNumber, TrackPayments, 'credit' type
  FROM users
 WHERE AccountNumber IN(2380, 2310, 2621);
```

Sample output:

```
| ACCOUNTNUMBER | TRACKPAYMENTS |   TYPE |
|---------------|---------------|--------|
|          2610 |             1 |  debit |
|          2620 |             1 |  debit |
|          5310 |             1 |  debit |
|          2310 |             1 | credit |
|          2380 |             0 | credit |
|          2621 |             1 | credit |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9bf5/5)** demo